# Definition of final functor

Tags: category-theory, definition

> A functor $G:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ is final when the
> following conditions are satisfied for every category $\mathcal{A}$
> and every functor $F:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathcal{A}$:
>
> 1. if the limit $(L,(p_D)_{D\in\mathcal{D}})$ of $F$ exists, then $(L,(p_{G(C)})_{C\in\mathcal{C}})$ is the limit of $F\circ G$;
> 2. if the limit $(L,(q_C)_{C\in\mathcal{C}})$ of $F\circ G$ exists, then the limit $F$ exists as well.
>
> Observe that in condition (2), applying condition (1) implies
> immediately that the limit of $F$ has the form
> $(L,(p_D)_{D\in\mathcal{D}})$ with $p_{G(C)}=q_C$ for
> $C\in\mathcal{C}$.

I don't see why applying (1) to (2) implies that $p_{G(C)}=q_C$ for $C\in\mathcal{C}$.

Let $(L,(q_C)_{C\in\mathcal{C}})$ be the limit of $F\circ G$. By (2), there exists a limit $(L,(p_D)_{D\in\mathcal{D}})$ of $F$. By (1), $(L,(p_{G(C)})_{C\in\mathcal{C}})$ is the limit of $F\circ G$. Thus there exists a unique isomorphism $r:K\rightarrow L$ such that $p_{G(C)}=q_C\circ r$ for $C\in\mathcal{C}$. But this doesn't show that $p_{G(C)}=q_C$. Abuse of notation, maybe?

Comment: I assume $K$ is the limit of $F$, probably a typo that you used $L$ twice? Yeah, it's kind of abuse of notation, but you can actually safely assume that $p_{G(C)}=q_C$ on the nose, since you can transfer the limit structure via the isomorphism $r$ from $K$ to $L$. I.e., if $(K,\{p_D\})$ is your limit of $F$, and $r:K\to L$ is an isomorphism, then $(L,\{p_D\circ r^{-1}\})$ is also a limit of $F$, and now $p_{G(C)}\circ r^{-1} = q_C\circ r\circ r^{-1} = q_C$, as desired.

Comment: I think you misinterpret the statement. The claim is that defining $p$ by the given equation gives a limit cone.